# How to deal with IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Let say I have these 3 classes.

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    //some base code here
}

class Foo : MyBase, IDisposable
{
    //got at least a field I should dispose
}

class Bar : MyBase, IDisposable
{
    //got at least a field I should dispose
}
```

I have a few classes like that. I got classes that own a `List<base>`. How could I dispose properly of all those classes without having to test/cast to get the proper type and then having `Dispose` ?

Comment: In future, please be more careful with your examples - follow .NET naming conventions (`foo` and `bar` => `Foo` and `Bar`), use the right interface name (`iDisposable` => `IDisposable`) and don't try to use keywords (`base`) as identifiers. These errors don't *stop* us from helping you, but they're unnecessarily distracting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If disposability is part of the contract of the base class, why not state it explicitly?

```
abstract class MyBase : IDisposable
{
    //some base code here

    //an abstract "implementation" of the interface
    public abstract void Dispose();
}
```

This way, you can be sure that all its descendants are in fact disposable. You can also create a collection class instead of a generic list, along the lines:

```
class MyBaseCollection : IEnumerable<MyBase>
{
    private List<MyBase> innerCollection;
    ....
    public void DisposeItems()
    {
       // call Dispose on each item here
    }
}
```

---

Proper disposal of unmanaged resources can be exceptionally tricky and proverbially resistant to debugging. When implementing the IDisposable interface on the concrete classes, you should follow the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).

In the abstract class itself, you can do several things depending on what you want to do with your class hierarchy.

- If all (or most) of the descendants will need disposing logic, you can force them to implement both method of the Dispose pattern using:

  ```
  public abstract void Dispose();
  public abstract void Dispose(bool disposing);
  ```

  This way the descendant has no choice but to implement the methods, otherwise the code does not compile.
- If most of the classes do not need disposing, but some of them still do, I would declare virtual methods in the base class:

  ```
  public virtual void Dispose(){
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){}
  ```

  This default implementation will be good enough for most descendants, and those that do need disposing can override it at will.
- Also, since the code of the `Dispose()` method is pretty much always the same, you can implement that one, and leave the other as virtual or even abstract.

  ```
  //should not be overridden
  public virtual void Dispose(){
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  //must be overriden
  public abstract void Dispose(bool disposing);
  ```

Comment: Should I implement `IDisposable` on MyBase even if it don't have anything to dispose?

Comment: @im_a_noob : If all (or even most) derived classes need `IDisposable` then it is a valid option. Compare with `System.IO.Stream` and note that a `MemoryStream` has nothing to Dispose.

Comment: No, just add `public abstract void Dispose();` so satisfy the compiler.

Comment: @SWeko - No, follow the std implementation pattern.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - the compiler balks with "'MyBase' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()'" if that line is not there. Although, depending on the scenario, `public virtual void Dispose(){}` might be a better option.

Comment: Look up the std pattern. You need a `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {}`.

Comment: [The Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) <-- Clicky

Comment: Added some explanation (and options) of implementing a disposable hierarchy

Comment: Cleanup via `Dispose` isn't really part of the contract for a class; it may be part of the contract for a *constructor* (possibly all of a class' constructors), or a *factory method* that returns a class reference, but not really the contract of the class itself.  The big question in deciding whether the base class should implement `IDisposable` is whether cleanup is at all likely to be part of the contract of any factory method which uses the base class as its return type.  If so, the base class should implement `IDisposable`.  If not, don't bother.

Comment: The `Dispose(bool)` overload should be `protected` rather than public.  Also, if any derivatives of a class are going to want to implement a thread-safe dispose, the parameterless dispose method of the base class should `Interlocked.Exchange` a protected `DisposeStarted` flag (of type `int` rather than `bool`) and only call `Dispose(true)` if it was false.  If the non-overridden base-class doesn't handle its dispose flag in this fashion, every derived class will have to add its own `Disposed` flag; much cleaner to just have one in the base.

Answer (score 8):

Well you can use:

```
foreach (var disposable in list.OfType<IDisposable>())
{
    disposable.Dispose(); 
}
```

I'd say it's *generally* a bad idea to have this sort of class hierarchy though; it means clients can't just use "any instance of `MyBase`" in the same way, as there are additional contracts for specific types. It would be cleaner to make `Base` implement `IDisposable`, even if a *few* specific types didn't actually require it.